# Getting connection reset when trying to ssh localhost

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I installed openssh using below command

```
apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

I'm trying to create ssh connection to localhost.

```
ssh user@localhost
```

I'm getting below error

```
Connection reset by 127.0.0.1 port 22
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try regenerating the host keys:

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* && sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

You can get more debug information from ssh with the -v option, as well as looking in the ssh server log, for debian/ubuntu, this is `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: I have seen this suggestion elsewhere, but am confused, is this command supposed to be run on the host machine or client? Am I just out of luck if ssh is my only means of accessing the host?

Comment: It needs to be done on the host server. You'll need some other way to get remote access if ssh is currently inoperable. kvm-over-ip, ipmi console, or rescue boot disk all come to mind.

Comment: You can also use `ssh-keygen -A -f /` to regenerate the host keys.